pouring concrete platform on existing concrete foundation
In preparation for installing a heat pump, we need to expand the existing platform on which the current heating unit sits by at least 6 cm. The room itself is long-ish and narrow. Our washer and dryer sit on a dedicated contrete platform in line next to the existing heating unit platform. It is a very tight fit. There is a gap of ca. 20cm between these two platforms. The entire floor surface, including these two platforms are tiled with stoneware, glazed tiles. The plan is to simply pour a concrete platform to fill the gap between the existing ones with no prior prep of the subflooring. The total required volume is 15.7 cubic meters of concrete/flooring screed. Our concerns are the load capacity and possible shifting of the new platform. We are not concerned about inconsequential cracking. We appreciate your expert advice.

15.7 cubic meters to fill that little gap? Check your math.

Yeah that looks like one bag's worth of concrete to me.

I think that "no prior prep" is a bad idea. The surface below the "patch" should be abraded (i.e. chiseled, scored, scratched, roughened) and dampened, to ensure adhesion. Ideally, steel (rebar) pins should be inserted into holes drilled into the surrounding slabs, and reinforcing wire mesh or rebar should be used within the patch; this strengthens the patch and ties it to the surrounding slabs and will help prevent movement.

I would clean the area well, then acid etch the tile and adjacent slab verticals with muriatic acid.
Then “paint” or spray the area with a concrete bonding agent before filling it with a concrete mixed with a vinyl modifier. Just use a short piece of lumber for the form on the open side.
If you want to overbuild it you could add some fiberglass chaff to the concrete mix also.
It won’t go anywhere since it is trapped on three sides and it’s not like you are building a road bed for truck traffic.
Good luck!
